# Using JSON to avoid using switch case because of too many cases

Tags: javascript, java, arrays, json, data-structures

I am having a piece of code where switch case is used to pick a value. I need this to be avoided as too many switch cases might become unreadable. Is there any way to store the values in a JSON file and pick the value from there and use wherever needed...? The code resembles to the code below.

```
public static Response postUser(String currency){
        switch(currency){
            case "GBP" :
                Query.setquery("mutation {" +currency+ "}...........");
            
            case "USD" :
                Query.setquery("mutation {" +currency+ "}...........");
            
            case "INR" :
                Query.setquery("mutation {" +currency+ "}...........");

                //so on and so forth (45 currencies)

}
            return Response;

}
```

I want to store the parameter of setquery method in Json file and call it here.

Comment: You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that people can understand your problem and help you. [see why you shouldn't post image as a code or an error](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question#:~:text=You%20should%20not%20post%20code,order%20to%20reproduce%20the%20problem.)

Comment: Right, show us two or three example of the switch-case, explain how many you actually have and explain what the range of data is and the end goal.  You could probably use a Map but it's hard to say for sure given the little information we have now.

Comment: @HR01M8055 : I disagree. His question is conceptual in nature and does not require any examples. He is simply looking for alternatives to large switch case statements that achieve the same local objective but in a more readable way.

Comment: The problem (for me at least) is that I'd do this with a Map but I don't know how to implement what the OP is asking.  In other words I really do need more information.

Comment: @LonnieBest OP should've added the code here at least. Are you really thinking to write the code from the image and then try to figure out how can you provide the solution.

Comment: @markspace: I too like the idea of using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) keys, where each key points to a function.

Comment: @markspace have edited the question. Sorry for not being clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

OK first if you are trying to localize currency then you should look at the localization already built-in to Java.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/numberFormat.html

Second your use appears simple enough to use a Map directly.

```
String[] init = {"GB", "Some string %s etc.",
                 "US", "More string %s blah",
                };
Map<String,String> locals = new HashMap<>();
for( int i = 0; i < init.length; i+=2 ) {
   locals.put( init[i], init[i+1] );
}

// ...

public static postUser(String currency){
  String f = locals.get( currency );
  return String.format( f, currency );
}
```

Make sure to [read the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,java.lang.Object...)) of `format` it's a bit involved.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead of switch. Here's an example that gives the general idea:

```js
let map = new Map();

map.set('GBP',function()
{
    console.log("GBP");
});

map.set('USD',function()
{
    console.log("USD");
});

map.set('INR',function()
{
    console.log("INR");
});

// Get function based on key and run if found:
let func = map.get("USD");

if (func)
{
  func();
}
```

Comment: I just noticed that your example (provided in your edit) is in java, but my answer is javascript. I leave this answer "as is" instead of deleting it (in hopes it helps someone else who comes across it).